# non-static replacement for println

Tags: java, static, non-static

easy question is there an other function i can use instead of println, because i want to output a non-static variable to a file usig out.println();

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class main {

String outputString ="Math.sqrt(25);" ;
static String outputPath ="src/output.txt";
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f;
    f= new File (outputPath);
        //file creation
        if(!f.exists()){
            f.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("File has been created");
        }else{
            f.delete();
            System.out.println("1. File has been deleted");
            f.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("2. File has been created");
        }
        //adding string(text) to file
        try{
            FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(args[0]);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);

            out.println(outputString);
            out.close();

        }catch(IOException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

if that is not posible maybe there is an whole other way to go around it. my main problem is that i want to make a string in to peace of code. But that seem to be hard to do :) any help on that :)

Comment: You can certainly print both static and non-static variables with _System.out.println_.  What are you trying to do that is not working?

Comment: @jahroy.. Given that he is not doing it inside a static method. Which is what troubling OP.

Comment: Hint: when the compiler outputs an error message and you don't understand it: copy the error message, and Google it: you'll find plenty of explanations of what it means and how to fix your code.

Comment: It would help if you clarified the question. It is hard to tell what is being asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `println()`. It has to do with the fact that, being non-`static`, `outputString` is associated with an *instance* of your class, and your code creates no such instance.

Either make `outputString` static, or create an instance of `main`:

```
public void doit(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ...
    PrintWriter out = ...;
    out.println(outputString);
    ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new main().doit(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `println` function can print both static and non-static variables.  The problem is that you're trying to access a non-static variable `outputString` from within a static context (your `main` method).

Answer (score 1):

`println` is a non-static method of the `PrintStream` class. `System`, also a class, has a static *member* called `out` of type `PrintStream` which you can retrieve via the `System.out` call. This member is initialized when java is started.

Note that this does not in any way imply that this is anything other than a regular `Object` of type `PrintStream`, it's just that it's a singleton that is conveniently accessible statically from System.